# Бескаскадный или безкаскадный?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, приставка

*Бескаскадный* или *безкаскадный*?

На слух *безкаскадный* звучит вернее. Так ли это?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: бескаскадный (чересстрочный и пр.). В современной орфографии перед глухой согласной "з" в приставке меняется на "с".

Answer (score 1):

Звук [к] глухой, поэтому мы должны писать перед ним С. Подробнее об этом можно почитать [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/128-sogl-19-14) (§50).